# OpenSSL iphone simulator crash SSL_load_error_strings API

Tags: iphone, ios4, openssl, ios-simulator

I am trying to use open ssl functions in my iphone application, tried to run the app on iphone simulator for iOS4 but it got crashed by giving following error:

---->SSL_load_error_strings() // using this function gives crash

"Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
strerror$UNIX2003 called from function ERR_load_ERR_strings in image mytestapp.
If you are encountering this problem running a simulator binary within gdb, make sure you 'set start-with-shell off' first."

I took openssl library from http://www.x2on.de/2010/02/01/tutorial-iphone-app-with-compiled-openssl-library/

Did anybody encountered same issue?

Comment: I got solution to my own query.. i was using libraries compiled for iphone device (libcrypto.a and libssl.a) for simulator. so it was crashing at entry point itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution to my own query.. i was using libraries compiled for iphone device (libcrypto.a and libssl.a) for simulator. so it was crashing at entry point itself.